# It is possible to use bootstrap admin template in one Meteor.js application?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm new student of Meteor.js and I just wanna know if it's possible to use bootstrap admin template in one Meteor.js application?

I try put Bootstrap template in my project but when i up the server return errors.

Comment: what errors are you getting? give us a link to the Bootstrap template. And put the code for how you are adding the template.

Comment: Unable to resolve some modules:

  "jquery" in                                 
/home/leonardo/Desktop/intermediated/metronic_v4.7.1/theme/assets/global/plugins/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.min.js
.... and several others files in the template

Comment: sounds like you need to import jquery package `meteor add jquery` or the npm module.

Comment: You already used  bootstrap admin templates in your meteor projects ?

Comment: no, is there a atmosphere package for it?

Comment: I buy bootstrap template and is this what i wanna put in my project

Comment: actually, there was a template that we used in our project before. we have recently revamped the site so I forgot about that. You would have to turn the html files into templates, and keep the css and js libraries in a public/theme folders that you import.